# Remove all polylines from map in version 3.0

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Is exists any method to clear all lines belongs to Polyline's method.
I tried a method poly.setMap(null) in my function clearPolylines().

for any help i will be very grateful.

[link to example in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eyray9tb/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
                <title>TODO supply a title</title>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
        <script>
        var centerLat;
        var centerLng;
        var mapOfSalons;
        var markers = [];
        var poly;


        function ajax() {
          var ajaxArray = [];
          ajaxArray[0] = {
            "lat": "50.22",
            "lng": "19.22",
            "text": "pos1"
          };
          ajaxArray[1] = {
            "lat": "49.00",
            "lng": "19.88",
            "text": "pos2"
          };
          ajaxArray[2] = {
            "lat": "49.40",
            "lng": "21.22",
             "text": "pos3"
      };
      ajaxArray[3] = {
        "lat": "49.90",
        "lng": "21.66",
        "text": "pos4"
      };

      ajaxArray[0].lat = Math.random() * 49;
      ajaxArray[2].lat = Math.random() * 49;

      return ajaxArray;
    }


    function ajax2() {
      var ajaxArray2 = [];
      ajaxArray2[0] = {
        "lat": "20.22",
        "lng": "19.22",
        "text": "dax1"
      };
      ajaxArray2[1] = {
        "lat": "20.00",
        "lng": "24.88",
        "text": "dax2"
      };

      ajaxArray2[0].lat = Math.random() * 30;
      return ajaxArray2;
    }


    $(document).ready(function() {
      onStart();
    });

    function generateHexColor() {
        hex = (parseInt(Math.random()*16777215)).toString(16);
        return '#'+hex;
    }

    function clearPolylines() {
         poly.setMap(null);
    }

    function clearOverlays() {
      for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        markers[i].setMap(null);
      }
      marker = [];
    }


    function onStart() {
  centerLat = 20.22;
  centerLng = 21.22;

  var mapProp = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(centerLat, centerLng),
    zoom: 3,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  mapOfSalons = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
  initialize();
}



function drwaUserRoad( data, color) {
    var path = [];

   clearPolylines();
   clearOverlays();

    poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
      strokeColor: color,
      strokeOpacity: 1.0,
      strokeWeight: 3
    });



  for (i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(data[i].lat, data[i].lng),
      map: mapOfSalons,
      title: data[i].text
    });
    path.push(marker.getPosition());
    markers.push(marker);
  }
  poly.setPath(path);
  poly.setMap(mapOfSalons);
}

function initialize() {
  clearOverlays();
  var data = ajax();
  var data2 = ajax2();
  drwaUserRoad(data, generateHexColor());
  drwaUserRoad(data2, generateHexColor());
  setTimeout(initialize, 10000);
}
</script>

    </head>
    <body style="margin: 0 auto;">
        <div id="googleMap" style="width:100%;height:100vh;"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This should help you out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28095737/clear-polyline-from-google-maps-and-then-restart-it/28096088#28096088

Comment: Are you just trying to fix the issue with the polylines staying left behind? My answer to [your previous question (connect groups of marker by polyline)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32446592/connect-groups-of-marker-by-polyline/32447615#32447615) should handle the issue in your fiddle.  If that isn't the question, how/when are you planning on removing them?

Comment: every call the timeout I am going to clear map with markers & polylines, but i dunno how i cam make it :(

Comment: @geocodezip - your solution is good for two lines, but someties i need a more lines of different colors. Do you have any idea??

Comment: Extend the solution.  Keep references to all the polylines you need to remove.